# How to install Intel graphics drivers (with Vulkan support) for Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial?

Tags: intel, drivers, vulkan

I'm trying to get Vulkan running on my linux laptop. I've tried this:

https://launchpad.net/~canonical-x/+archive/ubuntu/vulkan

from here:
https://01.org/linuxgraphics/blogs/jekstrand/2016/open-source-vulkan-drivers-intel-hardware

But the packages have been purged from the PPA. How can I get Intel
Vulkan drivers for Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the PPA from https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/mesa

It's mostly up-to-date and also includes Vulkan drivers for Intel GPUs. I'm using that one too for development.

Answer (score 2):

The [padoka PPA](https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/mesa) (linked in Sascha Willems's answer) worked for me as well, on Ubuntu 16.04.

After adding the PPA to apt, I did the following:

1. `sudo apt upgrade libglapi-mesa libgl1-mesa-dri vulkan-utils`
2. For some reason I had to create an extra symlink for the intel driver:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libvulkan_intel.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so
   ```